# Resizing background images for Responsive Mobile Web Design With Media Queries and Bootstrap 4

Tags: background-image, bootstrap-4, responsive

I'm using the following code to resize the images...  Basically, I would be swapping out the image as the screen sizes shrinks or gets wider.   I was wondering if this is the right approach and what size images would I have to use for each breakpoint in the media queries?

Here is a snippet of my CSS code for the background image.  BTW...  I'm using "no-gutters" in bootstrap 4 to layout the site.  But when the images get smaller they just show parts of the background.  I want to either create a new image (resized) or have it shrink to display the proper background.

Any ideas of what size to resize the images to or how to shrink/expand them?  The default starting image is 2000x1333px.

```css
.landpage-img {
  background: url(../img/bg-neon-01-2000x1333.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  height: 1333px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  .landpage-img {
    background: url(../img/bg-neon-01-2000x1333.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat center center fixed !important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .landpage-img {
    background: url('../img/bg-neon-01-2000x1333.jpg') 50% 80% no-repeat fixed !important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .landpage-img {
    background: url('../img/bg-neon-01-2000x1333.jpg') 50% 80% no-repeat fixed !important;
    background-size: auto !important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```